# Duplicate indexes ONLY after call to zoo object column

Tags: r, zoo

Basically, I have a zoo object indexed by a concatenated POSIXct date/time object. Everything looks fine, but when I make the call:

```
zoo$Close
```

The column returned shows a duplicate of indices and prices.

I bet it has something to do with the roundabout way I'm reading in and creating the zoo object via data frame, but I'm at a total loss for more streamlined ways to do it while simultaneously pasting the date and time columns together to form the index.

Some code for reading in my file:

```
getData = function(filename){

    data = read.table(filename, col.names = c("Date", "Time", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close", "Volume", "Bid", "Ask", "BA Spread"))
    data1 = data
    data[["Date"]] = data[["Time"]] = NULL

    zoo = zoo(data)
    index(zoo) = as.POSIXct(paste(data1[["Date"]], data1[["Time"]]))

    return(zoo)
}
```

Data in 1-minute intervals, and in a whitespace-separated file like so: (lines spill over a bit here)

```
2012-06-01 06:00 134.32812500 134.31250000 134.32812500 134.32812500 710 134.32812500  134.34375000 0.01596653

2012-06-01 06:01 134.34375000 134.32812500 134.32812500 134.34375000 127 134.34375000 134.35937500 0.01566084
```

After the call zoo$Close, I get something that begins like:

```
2012-06-01 06:00 134.32812500

2012-06-01 06:00 134.32812500

2012-06-01 06:01 134.34375000

2012-06-01 06:01 134.34375000
```

I'm at the end of my rope here, relatively new to R still, any guidance would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: output from dput(head(data)):

> dput(head(data))

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2012-06-01", 
"2012-06-04", "2012-06-05", "2012-06-06", "2012-06-07", "2012-06-08", 
"2012-06-11", "2012-06-12", "2012-06-13", "2012-06-14", "2012-06-15", 
"2012-06-18", "2012-06-19", "2012-06-20", "2012-06-21", "2012-06-22", 
"2012-06-25", "2012-06-26", "2012-06-27", "2012-06-28", "2012-06-29"
), class = "factor"), Time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("06:00", 
"06:01", "06:02", "06:03", "06:04", "06:05", "06:06", "06:07", 
"06:08", "06:09", "06:10", "06:11", "06:12", "06:13", "06:14", 
"06:15", "06:16", "06:17", "06:18", "06:19", "06:20", "06:21", 
"06:22", "06:23", "06:24", "06:25", "06:26", "06:27", "06:28", 
"06:29", "06:30", "06:31", "06:32", "06:33", "06:34", "06:35", 
"06:36", "06:37", "06:38", "06:39", "06:40", "06:41", "06:42", 
"06:43", "06:44", "06:45", "06:46", "06:47", "06:48", "06:49", 
"06:50", "06:51", "06:52", "06:53", "06:54", "06:55", "06:56", 
"06:57", "06:58", "06:59", "07:00", "07:01", "07:02", "07:03", 
"07:04", "07:05", "07:06", "07:07", "07:08", "07:09", "07:10", 
"07:11", "07:12", "07:13", "07:14", "07:15", "07:16", "07:17", 
"07:18", "07:19", "07:20", "07:21", "07:22", "07:23", "07:24", 
"07:25", "07:26", "07:27", "07:28", "07:29", "07:30", "07:31", 
"07:32", "07:33", "07:34", "07:35", "07:36", "07:37", "07:38", 
"07:39", "07:40", "07:41", "07:42", "07:43", "07:44", "07:45", 
"07:46", "07:47", "07:48", "07:49", "07:50", "07:51", "07:52", 
"07:53", "07:54", "07:55", "07:56", "07:57", "07:58", "07:59", 
"08:00", "08:01", "08:02", "08:03", "08:04", "08:05", "08:06", 
"08:07", "08:08", "08:09", "08:10", "08:11", "08:12", "08:13", 
"08:14", "08:15", "08:16", "08:17", "08:18", "08:19", "08:20", 
"08:21", "08:22", "08:23", "08:24", "08:25", "08:26", "08:27", 
"08:28", "08:29", "08:30", "08:31", "08:32", "08:33", "08:34", 
"08:35", "08:36", "08:37", "08:38", "08:39", "08:40", "08:41", 
"08:42", "08:43", "08:44", "08:45", "08:46", "08:47", "08:48", 
"08:49", "08:50", "08:51", "08:52", "08:53", "08:54", "08:55", 
"08:56", "08:57", "08:58", "08:59", "09:00", "09:01", "09:02", 
"09:03", "09:04", "09:05", "09:06", "09:07", "09:08", "09:09", 
"09:10", "09:11", "09:12", "09:13", "09:14", "09:15", "09:16", 
"09:17", "09:18", "09:19", "09:20", "09:21", "09:22", "09:23", 
"09:24", "09:25", "09:26", "09:27", "09:28", "09:29", "09:30", 
"09:31", "09:32", "09:33", "09:34", "09:35", "09:36", "09:37", 
"09:38", "09:39", "09:40", "09:41", "09:42", "09:43", "09:44", 
"09:45", "09:46", "09:47", "09:48", "09:49", "09:50", "09:51", 
"09:52", "09:53", "09:54", "09:55", "09:56", "09:57", "09:58", 
"09:59", "10:00", "10:01", "10:02", "10:03", "10:04", "10:05", 
"10:06", "10:07", "10:08", "10:09", "10:10", "10:11", "10:12", 
"10:13", "10:14", "10:15", "10:16", "10:17", "10:18", "10:19", 
"10:20", "10:21", "10:22", "10:23", "10:24", "10:25", "10:26", 
"10:27", "10:28", "10:29", "10:30", "10:31", "10:32", "10:33", 
"10:34", "10:35", "10:36", "10:37", "10:38", "10:39", "10:40", 
"10:41", "10:42", "10:43", "10:44", "10:45", "10:46", "10:47", 
"10:48", "10:49", "10:50", "10:51", "10:52", "10:53", "10:54", 
"10:55", "10:56", "10:57", "10:58", "10:59", "11:00", "11:01", 
"11:02", "11:03", "11:04", "11:05", "11:06", "11:07", "11:08", 
"11:09", "11:10", "11:11", "11:12", "11:13", "11:14", "11:15", 
"11:16", "11:17", "11:18", "11:19", "11:20", "11:21", "11:22", 
"11:23", "11:24", "11:25", "11:26", "11:27", "11:28", "11:29", 
"11:30", "11:31", "11:32", "11:33", "11:34", "11:35", "11:36", 
"11:37", "11:38", "11:39", "11:40", "11:41", "11:42", "11:43", 
"11:44", "11:45", "11:46", "11:47", "11:48", "11:49", "11:50", 
"11:51", "11:52", "11:53", "11:54", "11:55", "11:56", "11:57", 
"11:58", "11:59", "12:00", "12:01", "12:02", "12:03", "12:04", 
"12:05", "12:06", "12:07", "12:08", "12:09", "12:10", "12:11", 
"12:12", "12:13", "12:14", "12:15", "12:16", "12:17", "12:18", 
"12:19", "12:20", "12:21", "12:22", "12:23", "12:24", "12:25", 
"12:26", "12:27", "12:28", "12:29", "12:30", "12:31", "12:32", 
"12:33", "12:34", "12:35", "12:36", "12:37", "12:38", "12:39", 
"12:40", "12:41", "12:42", "12:43", "12:44", "12:45", "12:46", 
"12:47", "12:48", "12:49", "12:50", "12:51", "12:52", "12:53", 
"12:54", "12:55", "12:56", "12:57", "12:58", "12:59", "13:00", 
"13:01", "13:02", "13:03", "13:04", "13:05", "13:06", "13:07", 
"13:08", "13:09", "13:10", "13:11", "13:12", "13:13", "13:14", 
"13:15", "13:16", "13:17", "13:18", "13:19", "13:20", "13:21", 
"13:22", "13:23", "13:24", "13:25", "13:26", "13:27", "13:28", 
"13:29", "13:30", "13:31", "13:32", "13:33", "13:34", "13:35", 
"13:36", "13:37", "13:38", "13:39", "13:40", "13:41", "13:42", 
"13:43", "13:44", "13:45", "13:46", "13:47", "13:48", "13:49", 
"13:50", "13:51", "13:52", "13:53", "13:54", "13:55", "13:56", 
"13:57", "13:58", "13:59", "14:00", "14:01", "14:02", "14:03", 
"14:04", "14:05", "14:06", "14:07", "14:08", "14:09", "14:10", 
"14:11", "14:12", "14:13", "14:14", "14:15", "14:16", "14:17", 
"14:18", "14:19", "14:20", "14:21", "14:22", "14:23", "14:24", 
"14:25", "14:26", "14:27", "14:28", "14:29", "14:30", "14:31", 
"14:32", "14:33", "14:34", "14:35", "14:36", "14:37", "14:38", 
"14:39", "14:40", "14:41", "14:42", "14:43", "14:44", "14:45", 
"14:46", "14:47", "14:48", "14:49", "14:50", "14:51", "14:52", 
"14:53", "14:54", "14:55", "14:56", "14:57", "14:58", "14:59", 
"15:00"), class = "factor"), High = c(134.328125, 134.34375, 
134.359375, 134.34375, 134.3125, 134.3125), Low = c(134.3125, 
134.328125, 134.328125, 134.3125, 134.28125, 134.28125), Open = c(134.328125, 
134.328125, 134.359375, 134.328125, 134.3125, 134.296875), Close = c(134.328125, 
134.34375, 134.328125, 134.3125, 134.28125, 134.296875), Volume = c(710L, 
127L, 2476L, 280L, 1064L, 1063L), Bid = c(134.328125, 134.34375, 
134.328125, 134.3125, 134.28125, 134.28125), Ask = c(134.34375, 
134.359375, 134.34375, 134.328125, 134.296875, 134.296875), BA.Spread = c(0.01596653, 
0.01566084, 0.01569884, 0.01568592, 0.015625, 0.01602079)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Time", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close", "Volume", "Bid", "Ask", 
"BA.Spread"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT 2: Ran sessionInfo()

```
R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.4.4 quantmod_0.3-17             
 [3] Defaults_1.1-1               forecast_3.22               
 [5] RcppArmadillo_0.3.2.3        Rcpp_0.9.10                 
 [7] fracdiff_1.4-1               tseries_0.10-28             
 [9] quadprog_1.5-4               TTR_0.21-1                  
[11] xts_0.8-6                    zoo_1.7-7                   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.14.2    lattice_0.20-0
```

FINAL EDIT: Started a new R session with only zoo package loaded as suggested, same result still returned. HOWEVER, this led me to a result that worked! I've been thinking about this problem for the better part of 24 hours. I just bypassed calling the zoo object column entirely by temporarily casting the zoo object as a data frame:

```
getCol = function(zooObject, colname){
    frame = as.data.frame(zooObject)
    col = frame[[colname]]
    colzoo = zoo(col)
    index(colzoo) = index(zooObject)

    return(colzoo)
}
```

Thank god that's over. Thanks to GSee for the guidance, much appreciated.

Comment: There are examples of how to do this in the [Reading Data in zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-read.pdf) (PDF) vignette.  Do you still have issues when you use `read.zoo`?

Comment: FYI, there's an `order.by` argument to `zoo` so you don't have to set the `index` separately.  that link @JoshuaUlrich provided is a good one; you should read it.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question; add it as an answer to your question.  IMHO, that seems like a very poor solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Thanks for the `dput` output.  You're using `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` which is the default for `read.table`.  Just add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your `read.table` call, and you should be good to go.

```
data <- read.table(text="2012-06-01 06:00 134.32812500 134.31250000 134.32812500 134.32812500 710 134.32812500  134.34375000 0.01596653
2012-06-01 06:01 134.34375000 134.32812500 134.32812500 134.34375000 127 134.34375000 134.35937500 0.01566084",
col.names = c("Date", "Time", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close", "Volume", "Bid", "Ask", "BA Spread"), 
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data
#        Date  Time     High      Low     Open    Close Volume      Bid      Ask      BA.Spread
#1 2012-06-01 06:00 134.3281 134.3125 134.3281 134.3281    710 134.3281 134.3438 0.01596653
#2 2012-06-01 06:01 134.3438 134.3281 134.3281 134.3438    127 134.3438 134.3594 0.01566084
data1 = data
data[["Date"]] = data[["Time"]] = NULL
zoo = zoo(data)
index(zoo) = as.POSIXct(paste(data1[["Date"]], data1[["Time"]]))
zoo
#                        High      Low     Open    Close Volume      Bid      Ask  BA.Spread
#2012-06-01 06:00:00 134.3281 134.3125 134.3281 134.3281    710 134.3281 134.3438 0.01596653
#2012-06-01 06:01:00 134.3438 134.3281 134.3281 134.3438    127 134.3438 134.3594 0.01566084
zoo$Close
#2012-06-01 06:00:00 2012-06-01 06:01:00 
#           134.3281            134.3438
```

Comment: Could it be a size scaling issue? My data set in is very large, over 22,000 rows long.

Comment: after you `read.table`, run `dput(head(data))` and add the output from that to your question

Comment: Thought that would do it, but unfortunately the output remains:

Close
2012-06-01 06:00:00 134.3281

2012-06-01 06:00:00 134.3281

2012-06-01 06:01:00 134.3438

2012-06-01 06:01:00 134.3438

2012-06-01 06:02:00 134.3281

2012-06-01 06:02:00 134.3281

Comment: Huh.  Your code works for me with the data you `dput` (even without stringsAsFactors=FALSE).  22,000 isn't all that long when you're talking about intraday data.  Please add the output of `sessionInfo` to your question

Comment: Since the problem does not occur with the data provided, I don't think I'm going to find a solution.  Edit the question when you can make the problem *reproducible*.  Otherwise, I think this should be closed as too localized.

Comment: You're honestly probably right that the problem was heavily localized. However, I finally got something that works. I appreciate all the quick help very much, thanks.